# Request parameter $filter could not be resolved when filtering a column name with spaces

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to use this endpoint of rest-api to filter my data extension by date, and it works well, when the date column name is a normal string like "fecha". However, when the column name has spaces like "Fecha de registro", it raises an error saying "Request parameter $filter could not be resolved". I tried to use %20 to format correctly the request url, however it is not working and it raises the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Example:
This doesn't work:
[https://mcgtxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/AAAAAA/rowset?$filter=Fecha%20de%20registro%20between%20'2022-12-01T00:00:00'%20and%20'2022-12-02T00:00:00'](https://mcgtxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/AAAAAA/rowset?$filter=Fecha%20de%20registro%20between%20%272022-12-01T00:00:00%27%20and%20%272022-12-02T00:00:00%27)

But this works:
[https://mcgtxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/AAAAAA/rowset?$filter=fecha%20de%20registro%20between%20'2022-12-01T00:00:00'%20and%20'2022-12-02T00:00:00'](https://mcgtxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/AAAAAA/rowset?$filter=fecha%20de%20registro%20between%20%272022-12-01T00:00:00%27%20and%20%272022-12-02T00:00:00%27)

Thank you.

Comment: Try `+` instead of `%20`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @sfdcfox comment, you can try like this on your filter endpoint. Replace `+` to the column space name

```
https://mcgtxxxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/AAAAAA/rowset?$filter=fecha+de+registro%20between%20'2022-12-01T00:00:00'%20and%20'2022-12-02T00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!